# Header does not refresh after adding #reply

Tags: php, header

```
if (strlen($_POST['reply']) < 6) {
header("Refresh: 2; url=thread.php?id=$tid#reply");
die("The text you have entered is too short. Please write a longer text and try again.");
}
```

Why won't header refresh work when I add `#reply`? Gives a blank page. It works with header location though. Any idea?

Comment: The code works perfectly on my server/browser. Are you sure, it's not something else that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Anything after hash sign (#) is a local part of the URL and shouldn't force refresh. Also, if you have `#reply` in the URL in browser and press enter again in address bar, the page is not refreshed, you are just taken to the #reply part (target)  of the page.

Also note, you are breaking standards by not using full URL. You should be using:

```
url=http://server.com/thread.php?id=$tid#reply
```

PS: I would recommend using `Header("Location: xxxxxxxx");`
you should put refresh in the META tag.