# How to Refresh Client Browsers From Server

Tags: php, jquery

I have to do an online live presentation and i need to know if it is possible to refresh Client browsers from my side or not? if so can you please give an idea how i can do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554517/header-refresh

Comment: It's possible but it's time for you to learn ajax. [5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)

Comment: Hi Siamak, isn't Ajax client side scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is referred to as server-side push. There are some libraries that do this, like Node.js, socket.io, Comet. Check this as well: [jQuery server side push with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039913/jquery-server-side-push-with-ajax)

Some people have been referring to AJAX. Using AJAX you can program your clients to initiate an HTTP request, so you can program them to make a request every 5 seconds, for example, in order to refresh their content.

Think of a chatting application where you want to update the client with what others submitted. If you use AJAX only, you'd need to refresh the client's page every while. If you use server-side push, you'll be able to maintain a connection between the server and the client, and send things whenever you like.

Some platforms (e.g. Google App Engine) refer to their server-side push API as the "Channel API"

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Node.js and socket.io.
Read here for learn : http://socket.io/